# How do I get current window size(or basically screen size on iOS) in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I need to get size of a window that current SwiftUI View placed in.

I know there's a `UIScreen.main.bounds` solution, but it says it will be deprecated in a future version. When I try `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow` it says it's deprecated in iOS 13, same with `UIApplication.shared.windows`, except it's deprecated in iOS 15.

Deprecation messages suggests me to use `UIWindowScene` to get current window, but it seems like the only way to access current window scene is in `UIView`

Is there a way to get the size of that current window in `SwiftUI`(hopefully without involving `UIKit`)?

Comment: Read about `GeometryReader`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `GeometryReader` its not spesific about screen size but size of area it covers. So if you add it first in your view hierarchy you can get size of screen.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            let size = proxy.size // -> screen size
            VStack {
                Image(systemName: "globe")
                    .imageScale(.large)
                    .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
                Text("Hello, world!")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

GeometryReader covers all available space for it so you can use to get screen size.

Comment: I did think of that, but I thought there is a cleaner way, like getting it from `Environment`. But seems like this is the only way

Comment: Note that in Catalyst, you will get a size of the window interior (excluding the title bar) this way!